# how to remove empty document if it not matched in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Could you please tell me how to remove empty documents if conditions not matched in mongoDB

I tried this query on shell

```
db.address.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
            "applications": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$applications",
                    "as": "applications",
                    "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$eq": ["$$applications.name", "DSB"] },
                            { "$in": ["$$applications.code", ["122018"]] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }}
])
```

**my collection**

```
[
  {
    "name": "test",
    "applications": [
      {
        "code": [
          "135001",
          "122017"
        ],
        "name": "HELLO"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "test1",
    "applications": [
      {
        "name": "HELLO",
        "code": [
          "135001",
          "122017"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "applications": [
      {
        "code": [
          "135001",
          "122017"
        ],
        "name": "HELLO"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "test3",
    "applications": [
      {
        "code": [
          "135001",
          "122017"
        ],
        "name": "HELLO"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "test4",
    "applications": [
      {
        "code": [
          "135001",
          "122017"
        ],
        "name": "HELLO"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "test5",
    "applications": [
      {
        "code": [
          "135001",
          "122017"
        ],
        "name": "HELLO"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "tes3",
    "applications": [
      {
        "code": [
        ],
        "name": "HELLO"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "test22",
    "applications": [
      {
        "code": [
          "135001",
          "122017"
        ],
        "name": "DSB"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "test89",
    "applications": [
      {
        "code": [
          "135001",
          "122017"
        ],
        "name": "DSB"
      },
      {
        "code": [
          "135001",
          "122017"
        ],
        "name": "HELLO"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "test89",
    "applications": [
      {
        "code": [
          "135001",
          "122018"
        ],
        "name": "DSB"
      },
      {
        "code": [
          "135001",
          "122017"
        ],
        "name": "HELLO"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

expected output

```
   [
  {
    "name": "test89",
    "applications": [
      {
        "code": [
          "135001",
          "122018"
        ],
        "name": "DSB"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**getting out put**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4143269d7b3f8883605a1e"), "applications" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4143269d7b3f8883605a1f"), "applications" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4143269d7b3f8883605a20"), "applications" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4143269d7b3f8883605a21"), "applications" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4143269d7b3f8883605a22"), "applications" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4143269d7b3f8883605a23"), "applications" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4143269d7b3f8883605a24"), "applications" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4143269d7b3f8883605a25"), "applications" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4143269d7b3f8883605a26"), "applications" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4143269d7b3f8883605a27"), "applications" : [ ] }
```

Please suggest why I am not getting expected output ??

I want to filter my collection which have `application` name ‘DSB’ and have code `122018`

See my expected output which have only one document which fulfil my condition  have name `DSB` and code '122018'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and there is position issue in your `$in` condition

```
db.address.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "applications": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$applications",
                    "as": "applications",
                    "cond":  {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$in": ['122018',"$$applications.code"] },
                            { "$eq": ["$$applications.name", "DSB"] },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            name:true
        }
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$applications", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false } }
])
```